# How to generate keypress event programmatically

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to develop a GTK application in Linux. In this scenario I do not have a keyboard attached, and I need to generate `key_press_event` for GTK.

I have written a multithreaded program to generate key press, but it works only once; after that the keypress is not getting generated.

`GtkWidget *window;` is declared as global in order to get the same window handler for both threads.

The program has 2 threads. The first holds the GTK main and gtk screen display code. The second generates key events according to user requirements.

I ported the `if()` block into my code, but the result is the same.

The signal is generated once. After that it's not coming to 2nd thread (signal generation thread).

I have put some debug prints, but they are not executed. It seems to be waiting on `gtk_main` in the first thread.

My code is the following:

```
void S1(void)
{
    GtkWidget *Win_1;
    GtkBuilder *builder;        
    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "/home/glade/glade1.glade", NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "Win_1"));        
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (kp_event), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main(); 
}

kp_event()
{
    gtk_widget_destroy (window);            
    S2();
}
```

`S2` is the same as `S1`, only differing in their screen item. I am calling `S2` from keypress handler of `S1` and vice versa.

Since I have no keyboards attached, I need to change two screens based on some user input via sockets or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2004-July/msg00036.html), particularly the following snippet of code:

---

```
/* synthesize Alt+O key press */
event = gdk_event_new (GDK_KEY_PRESS);
event->key.window = widget->window;
```

This line should actually read:

```
event->key.window = g_object_ref (widget->window);
```

Otherwise you'll get interesting error messages later on if you destroy
widgets.  Took some time to figure out for myself. :)

---

Comment: Thanks jcoppens, Really this comments helped .was confused on key generation for few days.this code is working.Shall i ask 1 more doubt;while in timer function call  only this key is generated , but using the same code how to generate key event without timer

Comment: You can extract the code from the timeout function (the  entire `if (gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keyval` (included) statement) and put it in a separate function. This was just to show how to send a key after 2 seconds.